# bot.polling python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

у меня в коде создается переменная и ей задается начальное значение но оно постоянно перезаписывается хотя должно сохраняться то что выбрал пользователь, но без начального значения нельзя так как оно используется до выбора пользователя(язык общения с пользователем)

вот фрагменты кода:

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
from googletrans import Translator

global lang
lang = 'RU'

translator = Translator()
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['commands'])
def commands(message):
    print("Id: " + str(message.from_user.id) + "\nFirst Name: " + str(message.from_user.first_name) + "\nText: " + str(message.text) + "\n")
    res = translator.translate("У меня присутствуют такие команды как:", dest = lang)
    print(lang)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, res.text + "\n1)/start(/go)\n2)/settings\n3)/help\n4)/weather\n5)/language")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['language'])
def commands(message):
    print("Id: " + str(message.from_user.id) + "\nFirst Name: " + str(message.from_user.first_name) + "\nText: " + str(message.text) + "\n")

    markuplang =  types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    EN = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Английский", callback_data = 'EN')
    RU = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Русский", callback_data = 'RU')

    markuplang.add(EN, RU)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На каком языке вам удобнее общатся?", reply_markup=markuplang)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'EN' or call.data == 'RU')

def calback_inline(call):
        try:
            if call.message:
                if call.data == 'RU':
                        lang = 'RU'
                        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Хорошо, теперь буду общатся с вами на русском")

                elif call.data == 'EN':
                        lang = 'EN'
                        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ok, now I will communicate with you in English")

                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text= "На каком языке вам удобнее общатся?" , reply_markup=None)  

        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

bot.polling( none_stop = True )
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать базу данных (например sqlite3), храните в ней необходимые значения, например:
Таблица пользователи:
1) id
2) telegram_id
3) lang
При первом обращении пользователя к боту, сохраняйте его id (Дополнительно есть возможность сохранить значение языка по умолчанию, так как в получаемом от пользователя сообщении, есть код языка. В message есть - 'language_code' со значением).
Если пользователь отвечает на команду ['language'], сохраняйте в базу данных значение. Сделайте возможным для пользователя изменить язык. (При изменении языка, обновляйте значение в базе данных).